# Django pass context into another view from dispatch

Tags: django, django-views

I want to redirect users to either a ListView or DetailView based on their role through the SiteDispatchView. If DetailView, I want to pass the `request.user.site` into the DetailView, but I encounter: `AttributeError: Generic detail view SiteDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.`

My URL for the DetailView is `path('<int:pk>/', SiteDetailView.as_view(), name='detail-site'),`

(Note that site is a OnetoOneField with the Site and User models.)

```
# views.py
class SiteDispatchView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.role >= 2:
            return SiteDetailView.as_view()(request, self.request.user.site)
        else:
            return SiteListView.as_view()(request)

class SiteDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    template_name = "project_site/site_detail.html"
    context_object_name = "project_sites"
    model = Site

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("project_site:detail-site")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your SiteDetailView class needs an argument int:pk. So you must to add this argument to your return in both classes:

```
return reverse("project_site:detail-site", args=(request.user.site.id,))
```

EDIT:

As a tip, you should use **reverse_lazy()** instead of **reverse()** when working with classes.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy